# Wordpress preview_post_link

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am trying to alter the default "preview post" button when posting on wordpress as the site has a hacked wordpress install and the posts previews are not where they are suppose to be.

I found the hook `preview_post_link` now I am just trying to figure out how to make a little plugin that will fix the problem.

What I don't know how to do and why I am posting here is, using the `add_filter` to change the link

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'the_preview_fix' );

function the_preview_fix() {

    return;
}
```

all I need it to do is instead of going to its current link go to `www.website.com/blog/p/the-slug` as even though the draft post doesn't appear on the live site the link will still take me to a generated page :)

Thanks in advance for any and all help received

## EDIT FIXED IT!

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'the_preview_fix' );

function the_preview_fix() {
    $slug = basename(get_permalink());
    return "http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/p/$slug";
}
```

Comment: Post your fix as an answer and accept it so others will see that the question has been answered, even if you answered it yourself :)

Comment: Don't have enough rep to do that yet :(

Comment: Really? I understand you might not be able to accept your own answer, but you can't even answer questions period?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'the_preview_fix' );

function the_preview_fix() {
    $slug = basename(get_permalink());
    return "http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/p/$slug";
}
```

Comment: May I ask: Where did you put the code that fixed your problem? I'm in the same boat and unfamiliar with WP. TIA!

Comment: Found the answer: the code above needed to be appended to the functions.php file in my theme.